# How to open a VB.Net application from MS ACCESS form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Good Day everyone, Is there a possibility that I can open an VB.net application by clicking on one control in MS Access form?

If it's possible can you help me with the code? And if it's not possible is there a workaround solution to do that.

Comment: I've already done like this one on VB.NET Apps, Opening ACCESS project from VB.NET. here is my code  `Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\POST\Executables\CrewMaintenance\PandimanBillingSQL2003.mdb")`

Comment: Thats not a project thats a database file...

Comment: Yes but it's like a project. That Access file having a multiple form and connected to SQl Server for its database. What I want to do is to open vb.net application from access from just what i stated in my above question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and call the shell command...

```
 Dim stAppName As String

stAppName = "c:\full_path\app.exe"
Call Shell(stAppName, 1)
```

Comment: it always return a message "File not Found"  what might be the problem of running .net app?

Comment: `"\\MULTI-SERVER1\MedRport\BPI\BPI .NET\POSTtools\POST tools.application"` that is my path of the application. but there's always an error `Invalid procedure or argument`